# Course Value -1 All The Time

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, core-location

I have set this flag to info.plist file : Required device capabilities - gps and megnetometer

But the out put log shows all the time -1 for course values, following is the log :

2013-09-09 11:05:09.930 MapApp[143:907] <+23.05910024,+72.53762685> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 09/09/13 11:05:00 AM India Standard Time

```
@interface MAViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
    CLLocation *previousLocation;
    CLLocationManager *callMethod;
    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation;
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *bike;

@end


- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }

    NSLog("%@",currentLocation.course);

    self.bike.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);
    annotationView.image = self.bike.image;

    return annotationView;
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;
    if  (!newLocation)
        return;
    currentLocation = newLocation;
    previousLocation = oldLocation;
    if(currentLocation != nil)
    {
        if (myAnnotation)
        {
            [self.myMapView removeAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        }
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location title:@"Current Location" subTitle:nil];
        [self.myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your log shows that speed is invalid, too. So you are

either:
- not moving
- or more probably, you don't use GPS as location service: set accuracy to CLLAccuracyBest to make sure you get GPS location. course and speed, does not work with cell tower or wifi locationing.